# How can i get specific error messages from a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, validation, mongoose

I am trying to set up user validation in Mongoose and struggling to get the specific messages to appear.  Here is my model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [true, "Name required"]
    },
    email: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [true, "Email required"] 
    },
    password: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [true, "Password required"],
        minlength: [6, "Password must be at least six characters"]
     },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    albums: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Album"}]
})
```

I currently have this method to create a new user. I believe I will need to find a better way of seeing if the email exists, probably in the model, but for now this is what I have.

```
registerUser(req, res) {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body
    db.User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then(exists => {
            if (exists) res.redirect("/register")
            else {
                db.User.create({ name, email, password })
                    .then((err, res) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err.errors.password.message)
                    })
            }
        })
},
```

I am entering an invalid password length to try and get the message, but I get a large error:

```
(node:49238) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: password: Password must be at least six characters
[0]     at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/portfolio-projects/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2579:32)
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/portfolio-projects/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2399:17
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/portfolio-projects/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1220:9
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[0] (node:49238) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
[0] (node:49238) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What do I need to change in order to receive just the error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had issues in the past regarding this and this helped me solve the issue

```
if (err) {
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        console.error(Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message))
    }
}
```

This will return `Password must be at least six characters`

Comment: I tried this but still received the same error message.

Comment: Ok, it's added now

Comment: This worked.  Thank you! I originally had it set up as an async method. I will try to convert it back using what you posted.

Comment: `Async` method is way cleaner and easy to read! but yea both way works